# Ideal collection type for collection subsets and min-max element sets in java

Tags: collections, hashmap, max, min, treemap

I want to write a code using java collections which works on a subset (sub range ) of elements. I want to find the set of elements (Key,value(custom object)) with maximum and minimum values.

Basically I want a function which provides a subsets (K,V) of minimum and maximum values from the selected range for selecting.

The resulting element will be removed from the original collection.

```
public class mycol {
int x;
int y;

mycol(int x, int y, int index){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
TreeMap<Integer, mycol> mycollection = new TreeMap<Integer, mycol>();

max_x_coll = mycollection.set_of_elements_with_max_x();//or a collection.max() function to do the same
//I then want to then again filter this set based on min/max values of y and then remove this element from the original list.
```

Which collection type will be preferred in this case having (most if not all) inbuilt functionality for doing the same with minimal user defined code.

Comment: why not TreeMap itself? the elements in a TreeMap are already sorted

Comment: suppose in in a treemap I have following values in {K,V} format: {1,3},{2,4},{3,1},{4,4},{5,4}. I want a set of elements having max value- i.e. {2,4},{4,4},{5,4}. can I get this?